# Java. Read folder from 'resources' while executing JAR: URI is not hierarchical

Tags: java, url, jar, classloader, executable-jar

I put a folder *'profiles'* (contains language profiles, which I need to use when executing JAR)  into *'resources'* folder. To read it I write:

```
URL langProfilesURL = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("resources/profiles");
File langProfilesDir = new File(langProfilesURL.toURI());
```

It works ok when I run in IDE: the URL is ***file:/D:/CODING/HappyState/bin/resources/profiles***

But when I execute HappyState.jar I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
```

Where the URL is  ***jar:file:/D:/HappyState.jar!/resources/profiles***

Could you please tell me what to do in order to read 'profiles' folder correctly? Thank you very much!

Comment: To read resources from a jar, use, `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()`

Answer (score 0):

Use `Class.getResource()` method instead. This handles all the cases whether this project is on a flat filesystem or in a jar file or even on a remote http location.
However you should note that this approach will not allow you to do same things you do with the `File` (actually folder) object.

Comment: What do you mean by 'Class.getResource()'? Class does not contain such method

Comment: Check this please: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)

Comment: Does it mean : `Parser.class.getResource("resources/profiles")`, where Parser is the class where I write this code? Thank you!

Comment: Yes. However, you will most probably call this method for specific files in your `resources/profiles` folder instead of the folder itself.

Comment: Unfortunately, it returns `null` for URL. Could you give me another advice, please? Actually, I need the whole folder, because one of the libraries uses it.

Comment: If your library strictly requires working with folders. Than you might need to programmatically extract the resources in your jar file to an external folder and than feed that folder to the library. I would try to avoid something like this, if at all possible though. :(